# How to filter and refresh array object

Tags: jquery, reactjs, preact

I want to filter and refresh array object when I click on button. Here is my code:

```
    handleClick (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var el = event.target

        if (el.name === 'diploma') {
            this.setState({activeIndex: true})
            this.state.results.filter((el) =>
                el.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('diploma') > -1
            );
        } else {
            this.setState({activeIndex: false})
            this.state.results.filter((el) =>
                el.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('management') > -1
            );
        }
    }

    fetchAPI(url) {
        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status >= 400) {
                    throw new Error('Bad response from server');
                }
                return response.json();
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const that = this;
        const url = 'https://d1zh5hbzybtmpd.cloudfront.net/api/app/category/' + that.props.categoryId;


        that.fetchAPI(url).then((data) => {
            that.setState({
                result: data.category,
                results: data.courses.courses
            });
        });
    }

render({ }, { result={}, results=['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''] }) {
        return (
```

list is not refresh when `handleClick` action is fired. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `.filter()` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the array it was called on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the state for `results` to take effect. However, your code might also work in some cases but it will not be consistent and it is usually not a good idea to mutate state variable in your callbacks.

```
handleClick (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var el = event.target

    if (el.name === 'diploma') {
        const newResults = this.state.results.filter((el) =>
            el.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('diploma') > -1
        );
        this.setState({activeIndex: true, results: newResults});
    } else {
        const newResults = this.state.results.filter((el) =>
            el.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('management') > -1
        );
        this.setState({activeIndex: false, results: newResults});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want filter some object, just setState({results: newResults})

```
 handleClick (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var el = event.target

    if (el.name === 'diploma') {
        this.setState({
            activeIndex: true,
            results: this.state.results.filter(el => el.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('diploma') > -1)
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            activeIndex: false,
            results: this.state.results.filter((el) => el.title.toLowerCase().indexOf('management') > -1);
        })

    }
}
```